# How can i access instance variables in a higher up view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

I have a UIView class, classA, initiated inside of viewA, but viewA has other objects i want to access from classA. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access viewA from classA using the `superview` property of UIView.

```
viewA == [classA superview]
```

Comment: Using.. UIView *viewA [self superview] works as much as it doesn't create errors, but changing stuff doesn't do anything to the superview, for example background color.